# Groupby calculation for only one part of dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to make some calculations using two dataframes and a groupby code. However, I am not able to find the way to make these calculations only when my variable "date_int" is larger or equal than an specific number (e.g., 20180501; equivalent to date "2018-05-01").

In other words the groupby code that I am using does not consider only the relevant combinations (the ones starting on 2018-05-01) and does all the calculations for previous combinations. My pourpose is to save time and to have a code that only calculates for the combinations that I am looking for starting from 2018-05-01.

Below I give the two dataframes, the calculation (conflicting part of the code), and the expected result.

Dataframe 1 (df):

```py
idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
data = [{'place': 1}, {'place': 5}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 3},{'place': 1}, {'place': 6}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 5}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 3},{'place': 1}, {'place': 9}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 6}, {'place': 8}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['place'])
df.index.names=['date','name']
df=df.reset_index()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y') # http://strftime.org/
#df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['place'] = df.place.astype('float')
df['date_int'] = df['date'].astype('str').str.replace('-','').astype('int64')
df.set_index(['date_int','name'], inplace = True)
```

Dataframe 2 (df2):

```py
idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18','Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Aug-18',  'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),
       np.array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']),
       np.array(['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B','D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'])]
data = [{'xx': -4, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -4, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 6, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -4, 'win': -1},{'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -6, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 6, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -6, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx','win'])
df2.index.names=['date','i1', 'i2']
df2=df2.reset_index()
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'],format = '%b-%y') # http://strftime.org/
#df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2['xx'] = df2.xx.astype('float')
df2['date_int'] = df2['date'].astype('str').str.replace('-','').astype('int64')
df2=df2.drop(['date','index'], axis=1)
df2['date_int2']=df2['date_int']
df2.set_index(['date_int','i1','i2'], inplace = True)
```

The conflicting code (which doesn't do it for values of the variable "date_int" greater or equal than the number 20180501)

```py
df10=df.copy()
if (df10['date']>='2018-05-01').any():
    df10['output'] = (df2.assign(to_this = df2['xx'][df2['date_int2']>=20180501])).groupby(level=[1,2]).to_this.cumcount().sum(level=[0,1])
    df10['output'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

The expected outcome:

```py
               index       date  place  output
date_int name                                 
20180501 B         8 2018-05-01    3.0     0.0
20180601 A         9 2018-06-01    5.0     3.0
         B        10 2018-06-01    2.0     3.0
         C        11 2018-06-01    3.0     2.0
20180701 A        12 2018-07-01    1.0     0.0
20180801 B        13 2018-08-01    9.0     2.0
         C        14 2018-08-01    3.0     2.0
20180901 A        15 2018-09-01    2.0     3.0
         B        16 2018-09-01    7.0     3.0
20181001 C        17 2018-10-01    3.0     5.0
         A        18 2018-10-01    6.0     6.0
         B        19 2018-10-01    8.0     7.0
20181101 A        20 2018-11-01    2.0     0.0
20181201 B        21 2018-12-01    7.0     4.0
         C        22 2018-12-01    9.0     4.0
```

If you could elaborate on the code to make it work only when my variable "date_int" is larger or equal than a specific value it would be useful, as it will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Assuming that the code upto creating the `DataFrame` `df` is what you expect and the only change needed is to filter this `DataFrame` `df` to get the expected output shown above. Could you try use of `.loc` as: `df = df.loc[20180501:,:]`? It will filter the `df` to that expected output.

Comment: I don't want to filter the results, what I need is to run the code only when "date_int" is greater or equal to the specifc number. I need to save time omiting the calculations I don't need.

Comment: Okay. Then would it help if the entire code is put in a `function` that takes an argument for `date_in`. Inside the function an `if-statement` could decide if the code runs or not? If this is helps, I can post the code.

Comment: @NileshIngle It sounds like it will help. Thanks!

Comment: @NileshIngle It would be great to see your code. Could you do it?

Comment: Posted an answer below. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['date'].apply(pd.Timestamp.timestamp).astype(int)
```

Or

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).values.astype(int)
```

Comment: But where do I aplly that in my code? Where do I set the specific value?

Comment: Both of these operations can be vectorized.  You should *not* be using apply here.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answer my question. Can you please show how do I incorporate your comment on my code in order to obtain the expected result. Thank you!

Comment: Replace it at: df['date_int'] = ... df2['date_int'] = ...

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen sorry I don't get where to replace it  nor where do I place the speciic number for "date_it" which is 20180501. If you can be more detailed in your answer I would really preciate it. Thank you.

Comment: The lines where you assign your date_int column: df['date_int'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).values.astype(int)   and df2['date_int'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).values.astype(int)

Comment: For your date_int column, do you want it to be an integer formatted as 20180501 or timestamp?

Comment: @PramoteKuacharoen ineger formatted as 20180501 (note that I edited the question; df2 and my code a little diffrent to be more clear)

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**:

The updated code below uses a different approach. Rather than remove data from the `DataFrame` after it is created, it does not use that data at all. This is done by a `mask_it()` function. This function can be used to create a `boolean` `mask` based on the `date_int`. This `mask` can be applied to all the `arrays/lists` such as `idx`, `data` etc. to keep only those datapoints that are on or after the `date_int`. Next, these subset of indices/data are used to create the `DataFrame`.

**Notes**:

1. Code-1 below seems to be correct, but does not match the ouptut posted in the question. Here, `df1` and `df2` are created from already `masked` list of indices before any grouping. So, only dates of on or after the `date_int` are used. Therefore, `.cumcount()` may be correct. This may be important because `.group()` at `level=[1,2]` does not include any dates.
2. Code-2 below output matches the output posted in question, however it may not be correct. Because, here the grouping is done "before" any `dates` are removed. Thus, the `grouping` at `level=[1,2]` could include dates before `date_int`. This can be checked by using `df2.groupby(level=[1,2])['xx'].groups()`.

*Side-note: The updated code in the question is giving me a different expected output for `df10` than what is posted in the question*

**Code-1**:

```
### Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

### Create function for mask
def mask_it(date_int, xarray):
    # Create 'start_date'
    dt = str(date_int) # convert integer 'date_int' to string
    dt = datetime.datetime(year=int(dt[0:4]), month=int(dt[4:6]), day=int(dt[6:8])) # convert to date
    dtyear = dt.strftime("%y") # get last two digits of year
    dtmonth = dt.strftime("%B")[0:3] # get first three characters of month
    start_date = str(dtmonth)+'-'+str(dtyear)
    start_date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%b-%y')
    
    # Convert array dates from string to datetime
    xarray_NEW = np.array([ datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%b-%y') for i in xarray])
    print(type(start_date))
    # Create boolean mask
    mask = [i >= start_date for i in xarray_NEW]
    
    return mask



### Function to create `df1`
def start_date_df(date_int):
    
    # Index
    df1_idx_date = np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',])
    df1_idx_char = np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

    # Data
    df1_data = np.array([{'place': 1}, {'place': 5}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 3},{'place': 1}, {'place': 6}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 5}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 3},{'place': 1}, {'place': 9}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 6}, {'place': 8}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 9}])    


    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ### Subset by using mask_it
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    # Get mask
    mask1 = mask_it(date_int, df1_idx_date) 
    # Use mask
    df1_idx_date = df1_idx_date[mask1]
    df1_idx_char = df1_idx_char[mask1]
    df1_data = df1_data[mask1]
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   
    
    ### Get 'idx' and 'data'
    idx = [df1_idx_date, df1_idx_char]
    data = list(df1_data)

    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['place'])
    df.index.names=['date','name']
    df=df.reset_index()
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y') # http://strftime.org/
    #df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df['place'] = df.place.astype('float')
    df['date_int'] = df['date'].astype('str').str.replace('-','').astype('int64')
    df.set_index(['date_int','name'], inplace = True)


    return df


### Function to create 'df2'
def start_date_df2(date_int):
    
    # Index
    df2_idx_date = np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18','Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Aug-18',  'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',])
    df2_idx_char1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'])
    df2_idx_char2 = np.array(['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B','D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'])
    

    # Data
    df2_data = np.array([{'xx': -4, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -4, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 6, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -4, 'win': -1},{'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -6, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 6, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -6, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}])


    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ### Subset by using mask_it
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    # Get mask
    mask2 = mask_it(date_int, df2_idx_date) 
    # Use mask
    df2_idx_date = df2_idx_date[mask2]
    df2_idx_char1 = df2_idx_char1[mask2]
    df2_idx_char2 = df2_idx_char2[mask2]
    df2_data = df2_data[mask2]
    #::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
    
    ### Get 'idx' and 'data'
    idx = [df2_idx_date, df2_idx_char1, df2_idx_char2]
    data = list(df2_data)
    
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx','win'])
    df2.index.names=['date','i1', 'i2']
    df2=df2.reset_index()
    df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'],format = '%b-%y') # http://strftime.org/
    #df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df2['xx'] = df2.xx.astype('float')
    df2['date_int'] = df2['date'].astype('str').str.replace('-','').astype('int64')
    df2=df2.drop(['date','index'], axis=1)
    df2.set_index(['date_int','i1','i2'], inplace = True)
    
    
    #........................
    # Limit by date_int
    df2 = df2.groupby(level=[1,2])['xx'].cumcount().sum(level=[0,1]) 
    
    #df2 = df2.loc[date_int:,:]
    #........................
    
    return df2


### Get DataFrames based on 'date_int'
df = start_date_df(20180501)
df['output'] = start_date_df2(20180501)
df['output'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Output - 1

```
print(df)

               index       date  place  output
date_int name                                 
20180501 B         0 2018-05-01    3.0     0.0
20180601 A         1 2018-06-01    5.0     0.0
         B         2 2018-06-01    2.0     0.0
         C         3 2018-06-01    3.0     0.0
20180701 A         4 2018-07-01    1.0     0.0
20180801 B         5 2018-08-01    9.0     1.0
         C         6 2018-08-01    3.0     1.0
20180901 A         7 2018-09-01    2.0     1.0
         B         8 2018-09-01    7.0     1.0
20181001 C         9 2018-10-01    3.0     3.0
         A        10 2018-10-01    6.0     3.0
         B        11 2018-10-01    8.0     4.0
20181101 A        12 2018-11-01    2.0     0.0
20181201 B        13 2018-12-01    7.0     3.0
         C        14 2018-12-01    9.0     3.0
```

---

---

**Code - 2**:

```
### Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

### Create function for mask
def mask_it(date_int, xarray):
    # Create 'start_date'
    dt = str(date_int) # convert integer 'date_int' to string
    dt = datetime.datetime(year=int(dt[0:4]), month=int(dt[4:6]), day=int(dt[6:8])) # convert to date
    dtyear = dt.strftime("%y") # get last two digits of year
    dtmonth = dt.strftime("%B")[0:3] # get first three characters of month
    start_date = str(dtmonth)+'-'+str(dtyear)
    start_date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%b-%y')
    
    # Convert array dates from string to datetime
    xarray_NEW = np.array([ datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%b-%y') for i in xarray])
    print(type(start_date))
    # Create boolean mask
    mask = [i >= start_date for i in xarray_NEW]
    
    return mask



### Function to create `df1`
def start_date_df(date_int):
    
    # Index
    df1_idx_date = np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',])
    df1_idx_char = np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

    # Data
    df1_data = np.array([{'place': 1}, {'place': 5}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 3},{'place': 1}, {'place': 6}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 5}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 3},{'place': 1}, {'place': 9}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 3}, {'place': 6}, {'place': 8}, {'place': 2}, {'place': 7}, {'place': 9}])    


    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ### Subset by using mask_it
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    # Get mask
    mask1 = mask_it(date_int, df1_idx_date) 
    # Use mask
    df1_idx_date = df1_idx_date[mask1]
    df1_idx_char = df1_idx_char[mask1]
    df1_data = df1_data[mask1]
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   
    
    ### Get 'idx' and 'data'
    idx = [df1_idx_date, df1_idx_char]
    data = list(df1_data)

    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['place'])
    df.index.names=['date','name']
    df=df.reset_index()
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y') # http://strftime.org/
    #df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df['place'] = df.place.astype('float')
    df['date_int'] = df['date'].astype('str').str.replace('-','').astype('int64')
    df.set_index(['date_int','name'], inplace = True)


    return df


### Function to create 'df2'
def start_date_df2(date_int):
    
    # Index
    df2_idx_date = np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18','Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Aug-18',  'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',])
    df2_idx_char1 = np.array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'])
    df2_idx_char2 = np.array(['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B','D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B'])
    

    # Data
    df2_data = np.array([{'xx': -4, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -4, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 6, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -4, 'win': -1},{'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -6, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 4, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -1, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 1, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 6, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -6, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -3, 'win': -1}, {'xx': -5, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 3, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 5, 'win': 1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}, {'xx': -2, 'win': -1}, {'xx': 2, 'win': 1}])

    """
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ### Subset by using mask_it
    #:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    # Get mask
    mask2 = mask_it(date_int, df2_idx_date) 
    # Use mask
    df2_idx_date = df2_idx_date[mask2]
    df2_idx_char1 = df2_idx_char1[mask2]
    df2_idx_char2 = df2_idx_char2[mask2]
    df2_data = df2_data[mask2]
    #::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
    """
    
    ### Get 'idx' and 'data'
    idx = [df2_idx_date, df2_idx_char1, df2_idx_char2]
    data = list(df2_data)
    
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx','win'])
    df2.index.names=['date','i1', 'i2']
    df2=df2.reset_index()
    df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'],format = '%b-%y') # http://strftime.org/
    #df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
    df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df2['xx'] = df2.xx.astype('float')
    df2['date_int'] = df2['date'].astype('str').str.replace('-','').astype('int64')
    df2=df2.drop(['date','index'], axis=1)
    df2.set_index(['date_int','i1','i2'], inplace = True)
    
    
    #........................
    # Limit by date_int
    df2 = df2.groupby(level=[1,2])['xx'].cumcount().sum(level=[0,1]) 
    
    #df2 = df2.loc[date_int:,:]
    #........................
    
    return df2


### Get DataFrames based on 'date_int'
df = start_date_df(20180501)
df['output'] = start_date_df2(20180501)
df['output'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Output - 2:

```
print(df)

               index       date  place  output
date_int name                                 
20180501 B         0 2018-05-01    3.0     0.0
20180601 A         1 2018-06-01    5.0     3.0
         B         2 2018-06-01    2.0     3.0
         C         3 2018-06-01    3.0     2.0
20180701 A         4 2018-07-01    1.0     0.0
20180801 B         5 2018-08-01    9.0     2.0
         C         6 2018-08-01    3.0     2.0
20180901 A         7 2018-09-01    2.0     3.0
         B         8 2018-09-01    7.0     3.0
20181001 C         9 2018-10-01    3.0     5.0
         A        10 2018-10-01    6.0     6.0
         B        11 2018-10-01    8.0     7.0
20181101 A        12 2018-11-01    2.0     0.0
20181201 B        13 2018-12-01    7.0     4.0
         C        14 2018-12-01    9.0     4.0
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for...see the results above.

Comment: Thanks, updated the code, now the `output` is similar.

Comment: Ok, but it seems you are only filtering with loc. What  I need is to group wisely, so the code doesn't have to do the whole process df2 = df2.groupby(level=[1,2])['xx'].cumcount().sum(level=[0,1])

Comment: I edited the question (for df2 and my code) so it is more clear. Note that I try to group this time, but still don't get the results I need.

Comment: @MarioArend: (1) Updated `Code-1` and `Code-2` are posted with notes. Here, created a new function `.mask_it()` that filters the `indices` used to create the `DataFrame`. Thus, only relevant data is moved forward through the code. Hope it helps. (2) I am getting a different expected output for `d10` code, than what is posted in the question. However it should not matter with the answers posted, as they use the previous code and uses a different approach to check if a datapoint is before/on/after a specific `date_int.